# Docker_Error:-"socket.gaierror: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution" error comes while run celery on docker image

Tags: docker-compose

## Docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3"
services:
  web:
    # replace username/repo:tag with your name and image details
    image: sunilsuthar/sim
    deploy:
      replicas: 5
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: "0.1"
          memory: 50M
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
    ports:
      - "4004:80"
    networks:
      - webnet
  rabbit:
    hostname: rabbit
    image: sunilsuthar/query_with_rabbitmq
    environment:
      - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER=rvihzpae
      - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS=Z0AWdEAbJpjvy1btDRYqTq2lDoJcXHv7
    links:
      - rabbitmq  
    ports:
      - "15672:15672"
      - "5672:5672"
    tty: true
  celery:
    image: sunilsuthar/query_with_rabbitmq
    command: celery worker -l info -A app.celery 
    user: nobody
    volumes:
      - '.:/app'    
networks:
  webnet:
```

Answer (score 0):

Check whether your docker container is on the correct network and whether you can ping the server with rabbitmq. In my case firewall settings were reset and local network was unreachable from within the container. Restarting docker daemon resolved the issue.